# In SharePoint Online can I still index columns in a library after reaching the 5000 limit?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view-threshold, indexed-column

I know you could previously extend the threshold view in SharePoint On-Premise. In SharePoint Online can I still index columns in a library after reaching the 5000 list view limit? I'm assuming there's no way to extend the threshold?

Comment: Yes, no way to extend the threshold. How many documents you have currently in the library.

Comment: 5800 documents, can I still index the columns even though we've gone over the threshold?